How spring boot and tomcat manage multithreading
I would like to undarstand how tomcat and spring boot manage simuntenously requests on the same endpoint.
@RestController
public class SimpleRest {

    private static long counter;
    Random random = new Random();


    @GetMapping("/counter")
    long restCounter() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        incrementCounter();

        System.out.println("Thread name : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return getCounter();
    }

    public void incrementCounter() {
        for(long i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public long getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}

When i execute few requests (on few browser tabs) simultaneously http://localhost:8080/counter, then I get response:
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Counter : 1000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-2
Counter : 2000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-3
Counter : 3000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-4
Counter : 4000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-5
Counter : 5000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-6
Counter : 6000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-7
Counter : 7000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-8
Counter : 8000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-9
Counter : 9000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-10
Counter : 10000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Counter : 11000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-2
Counter : 12000000000
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-3
Counter : 13000000000
I expected that this counter wouldn't be working fine because i thought that each thread will be incrementing counter in the same time so the result will be different from expected. How it is happening that result is correct?
Example with Java threads.
@RestController
public class SimpleRest {

    private static long counter;
    Random random = new Random();


    @GetMapping("/counter")
    long restCounter() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Thread thread1 = new Thread( () -> {
            incrementCounter();
        });

        Thread thread2= new Thread( () -> {
            incrementCounter();
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();

        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        System.out.println("Thread name : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.println("Counter : " + getCounter());
        return getCounter();
    }

    public void incrementCounter() {
        for(long i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public long getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}

Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-1
Counter : 979913268
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-2
Counter : 1937440001
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-3
Counter : 2915854756
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-4
Counter : 3834402590
Thread name : http-nio-8080-exec-5
Counter : 4433349875
There is expected result, without 'synchronized' counter will be not working correctly.

Your second example is the correct behaviour in normal circumstances. I know nothing about Spring Boot. However, I can say it is not Tomcat behaviour, it has something to do with boot. It is somehow serialising execution. Look at the configuration options for boot.
